# BIND DNS to DNSSEC Converting Forwarder

Tags: debian, bind, internal-dns, dnssec, opendns

I have an internal only DNS server running on BIND 9.8.4 on Debian, this recurses and caches all queries other than internal domain (ourdomain.lan) to OpenDNS. What I am hoping to do is to have all internal queries secure or not "converted" to secure when recursion occurs so that all queries that leave our network are DNSSEC queries.

Comment: are you planning on requiring validated results?

Comment: @Rick Ideally Yes